# How To Recover Data That Has Been Overwritten

Tags: data-loader, leads, fields

Sorry in advance for the low grade of technicality that I can provide with this question, but I do not know SalesForce at all and the person leading me through this question has not a technical profile.

### The problem

Jenny works in a company which uses SalesForce as CRM system. She has overwritten some data into the `LEADS` tab (running a mass update, specifically she gave an `.xlsx` file containing the data to write, and the SysAdmin has inserted them into the system via the `data-loader`) :

[image]

However, she shouldn't have done this modification and the previous data seem now to be lost.

### The question

As of my imagination, once they have sent the `UPDATE` request to the database the old data have been deleted. However, looking a bit into the web (and again, I'm sorry but I really do not know SalesForce) it seems there are some recovery actions.

Reading at the above test case (please do not hesitate to ask additional questions if needed, we'll be glad to provide you with more info as much as possible), what are the actions you would think about in order to recover the data she has overwritten (if possible)?

Answer (score 2):

check if the fields were enabled with Field History. If so you are still golden with the old data. As this saves on the salesforce side which can still be retrieved.

Confirm me, we can take it up from there.

Comment: Hi Giene, thanks a lot for your help. She has heard about this option already. Would you mind telling me what happens if _yes they were enabled_ and if _not they were not_? Just to know all the possibilities, I'll go back to you as soon as she will have chance to check.

Comment: If you have happen to have the history tracking, then you can potentially run a  query like below `SELECT Id, IsDeleted, LeadId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM LeadHistory` this will give you the list of records how the transition happened. Respective administrator should be able to format all the old values in an excel and you can use that excel to load them back potentially another update to Leads.

Comment: Do let me know if you still need any more information.

Comment: From the above query `SELECT Id, IsDeleted, LeadId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM LeadHistory` you will potentially get the following information respectively. `FIELD` will give you the list of fields with API names and `OldValue` will have the previous value and `NewValue` which what you already have updated.

Comment: You may want to check if they had exported the old data at any point in past. You will have a copy of the old data in that case.